# Local time in Azure Data Explorer / Kusto timechart

Tags: azure-data-explorer

Timechart x-axis time is printed in UTC-2h, while it should be printed in UTC. Other chars, such us Columnchart, work fine (time is shown in UTC).
Is this an issue?
Is it possible to format time in charts? For instance, printing x-axis time in local time...

Timechart column in Azure Data Explorer is stored in UTC (Local time -2h in my location). 
When printing a columnchart, time in X-axis is printed in UTC (local time -2h) -> OK
[columnchart output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PvU3k.png)
When printing a timechart, time in x-axis is printed in UTC-2h (local time-4)-> KO 
[timechartoutput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KmUmY.png)

Azure Data Explorer query:

```
let min_t = toscalar (<tablename>  | summarize min(Timestamp));
let max_t = toscalar (<tablename>  | summarize max(Timestamp));
<tablename>
| make-series sum(TrxCount) on Timestamp in range(min_t, max_t, 30m )    
| render columnchart
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is indeed a bug.

It happens specifically after `make-series` so doing something like

`<tablename> | summarize sum(TrxCount) by bin(Timestamp, 30m) | render timechart`

should work (although it won't fill empty data like `make-series` does.